# How to add a Javascript event handler using asp.net ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, dom-events, asp.net-ajax

I am wondering how to add a Javascript event handler using asp.net ajax.
I need to add event handlers after ajax update because jQuery plugin  to sort tables doesn't work and the `onload` method to display a screen keyboard does not trigger as well.

Is there a way to do that?

Maybe I need to switch to some other ajax library or/and try Asp.Net MVC to accomplish?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery `live` method.

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work for me. I hope I haven't misused it. I'm going to try the JSON AJAX approach instead of Update pannels according to this link: http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: Without any examples of what you've tried, it's pretty hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. Anyway, if you are after to add an event handler to an element after partial update, check the following sample.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

---

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function() {
        if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack) {
            $addHandler($get("Button1"), "click", function() {
                alert("This is a test...");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It is what I was looking for, but my jquery sorting still fails along with jquery validation. I probably need to work on that more thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks this helped me re-style a table using jquery which was updated (recreated) using asp.net ajax